# 20.04 Snap has lost its mind?

Tags: software-center, snap, chromium

I noticed that suddenly Chromium wasn't showing in the Dock.
I went to open software, and it wasn't in the dock.
And, they weren't in programs...
I rebooted, and same thing...

Research showed to do this:

`sudo apt install --reinstall gnome-software`

I got back the software. It said Chrome was "installed", but it doesn't show among programs.

I uninstalled and went to:

`sudo apt install chromium-browser`

This hung the first time; worked after a reboot.

The software installed, and would run from the command line, but didn't show in programs.

`sudo apt remove --purge chromium-browser`

... and deleted everything I could find related to the browser.

Snap store thinks it's still installed.

Try to remove from the GUI and I get

`cannot remove chromium unable to perform the following tasks`

But, there's no list of impossible tasks ..

So, I tried

`sudo snap remove --purge chromium`

... which gives the following error:

`error: cannot perform the following tasks: - Remove snap "chromium" (2529) from the system (cannot parse systemctl output: "Bus n/a: changing state UNSET → OPENING")`

I appear to be stuck with no Chromium or any way to install it - and totally perplexed about what's up with the snap store.

I've uninstalled and reinstalled gnome-software, and the issue remains. There's some list somewhere that makes the store think Chromium is installed when it isn't.

Comment: Have you considered using a [non-snap version of chromium](https://www.chromium.org/getting-involved/download-chromium/)? I haven't used or tested any of these but it seems like you could avoid the headache of dealing with snap. That is, unless you need or prefer snap for the extra sandboxing capability.

Comment: Also, did you switch from bash to something else like zsh or fish? Sometimes people have trouble with snap applications not showing up [after switching the default shell from bash to something like fish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71080115/snap-applications-not-showing-in-show-applications-ubuntu-20-04).

Answer (score 0):

I just uninstalled snapd:

`sudo apt remove --purge snapd`

Did an apt update, a reboot, and then reinstalled snapd and the snap store.

I had to re-install several softwares, but nothing with significant configuration (other than Thunderbird), and I'll sort that by copy-pasting the directory.

Thanks for everyone here.